# move files by date stamp with batch

Tags: batch-file, hard-drive

I need to move a file from all folders on all hard drives modified within two dates. Because I am new to batch, please explain what it all means.

What I want:

> Search all folders in all hard drives for files modified from Nov 10,
>   2013 to Nov 11, 2013 Make folder in drive D:/backups/11_11 Move all
>   files found in the scan modified with in the dates and YEAR to the
>   folder made Create a text file with the log of all files moved,
>   errors, and time of moved (time of moved optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "date1=01/09/2013"
set "date2=31/10/2013"
set "SearchPath=D:/backups/11_11"
set "datestamp1=%date1:~6,4%%date1:~3,2%%date1:~0,2%"
set "datestamp2=%date2:~6,4%%date2:~3,2%%date2:~0,2%"

for %%a in ("%searchpath%\*") do (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/-. " %%b in ("%%~ta") do set "datestampF=%%~d%%~c%%~b"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    if "!datestampF!" gtr "%datestamp1%" if "!datestampF!" lss "%datestamp2%" echo move "!fname!" "DestinationFolder"
    endlocal
)
```

Remove the `echo` to get it working.

Comment: @foxidrive yes, you are right and I know this also. My code describes the basic procedure. And It's freeware, patches are welcome.

Comment: hehe  Then all it needs is to search every drive, and copy the files to the searchpath.  BTW, is the second searchpath variable a debugging line?

Comment: @foxidrive the user has to specify, what are `all drives`? What about USB sticks, network drives and CD ROM? And yes, this second %searchpath% setting line is from testing :)  -removed. Thanks!

Comment: `Search all folders in all hard drives for files` so he's after a routine to detect hard drives only.  Wmic might work there, if you feel like going to the effort - if the OP replies at all.